# iPad App Cookies Storage?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cookies, ipad, storage

I have an application that sends you to one website that shows a login form.

I've read up on cookies from the apple reference (http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSHTTPCookie/initWithProperties:)

I'm honestly just not understanding this at all.

Can someone please explain how to get cookies working for an app?  Post sample code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a helpful Blog entry including a sample code using Cookies in Cocoa Applications:

http://www.calaresu.eu/2009/06/20/using-cookies-with-cocoa-nshttpcookie/

Comment: Thanks, I will be looking at this tomorrow in detail.

Comment: Can you give a full demo of how to setup cookies with a UIWebView?  I'm extremely lost here still.

Comment: the link is broken, unfortunately.

Comment: @mostruash The original link is also available on archive.org, you can find it here: http://web.archive.org/web/20100901154843/http://www.calaresu.eu/2009/06/20/using-cookies-with-cocoa-nshttpcookie/